# Dataframe schema change based on filtered values while reading JSON

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a case where I am trying to read a json file consisting an overall structure

**overall json file schema:**

```
root
 |-- event: string (nullable = true)
 |-- eventid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- property1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- sub_property1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- sub_property2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- property2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- sub_property1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- sub_property2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- sub_property3: string (nullable = true)
```

Now depending on the type of event the properties might be populated or not. For `event = 'facebook_login'` the schema would be

**facebook_login schema:**

```
root
 |-- event: string (nullable = true)
 |-- eventid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- property1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- sub_property1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- property2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- sub_property1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- sub_property3: string (nullable = true)
```

and when `event = 'google_login'` the schema would be

**google_login schema:**

```
root
 |-- event: string (nullable = true)
 |-- eventid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- property1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- sub_property2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- property2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- sub_property2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- sub_property3: string (nullable = true)
```

The problem I am facing is when I read this file and try to filter events it gives the same schema as the overall file schema (of course giving null/missing values for missing properties)

```
json_df = df.read.json(json_file_path)
fb_login_df = json_df.filter("event='facebook_login'")
google_login_df = json_df.filter("event='google_login'")
fb_login_df.printSchema()
google_login_df.printSchema() # same schema output for both
```

Is there a way we can achieve this ? to have different schema structures based on the filtered value ?

P.S : I was thinking having custom schemas defined for each event type but that would not scale since there are thousands of different event types in the json file

Comment: Have you tried to use `schema_of_json` (https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.schema_of_json.html) on your filtered dfs, with `dropFieldIfAllNull=true` option?

Comment: What's the actual problem you are trying to solve?  You want to change the schema but why do you want to do this?  seems like an XY problem https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: With your existing design it would output the same schema. But the value would be missing(null) e.g for facebook event `property1. sub_property2` would be null. and similar for google event.
Once you have filtered event you can explode, drop null columns and then have the desired schema.

Comment: @mazaneicha : indeed that is one option I was trying but was thinking if there's anything more intutive.

Comment: @MattAndruff : The actual problem as highlighted is that I would want to separate different events  and later write to different tables. Currently spark applies the overall json schema to all the events (event though they are not the same structure).

Comment: You can't write them later without first representing them in a data frame (which implies a schema).  This is why the schema is the same for both. It has to create something that can encompass all the data in the dataframe that you are reading from.  Is it possible at the file level to separate the fields?

Answer (score 0):

give the schema when you read the json:

for a try.json which contains this:

```
[{"event":"a","eventid":"mol","property1":{"sub1":"ex ","sub2":"ni"},"property2":{"sub1":"exe","sub2":"ad","sub3":"qui"}},{"event":"s","eventid":"cul","property1":{"sub1":"et ","sub2":"ame"},"property2":{"sub1":"o","sub2":"q","sub3":"m"}}]
```

you can do:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType
structureSchema1 = StructType([
StructField('event', StringType(), True),
        StructField('eventid', StringType(), True),
        StructField('property1', StructType([
             StructField('sub1', StringType(), True)
             ])),
        StructField('property2', StructType([
             StructField('sub1', StringType(), True),
             StructField('sub3', StringType(), True)
             ]))])
structureSchema2 = StructType([
        StructField('event', StringType(), True),
        StructField('eventid', StringType(), True),
        StructField('property1', StructType([
             StructField('sub2', StringType(), True)
             ])),
        StructField('property2', StructType([
             StructField('sub2', StringType(), True),
             StructField('sub3', StringType(), True)
             ]))])
df1 = spark.read.schema(structureSchema1).json("./try.json")
df2 = spark.read.schema(structureSchema2).json("./try.json")
```

Comment: the thing is that these sub properties change and are dynamic , so creating the schema would not be the best solution I feel

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading the data in as text. 1 row = 1 event.
Filter the data. (Google/Facebook)
Use `[from_json][1]` to create the schema as needed.
You will have to store the data in it's own table as you can't mix schema's.